# "Trying to get property of non-object"

Tags: php, sql, database, dynamic, html-table

I am currently trying to display a table using PHP, with the following code:

```
$sqlQ = 'SELECT w_Continent.ID, w_Continent.NAME, w_Country.Name, w_Country.Continent
    FROM w_Continent JOIN w_Country 
    ON w_Continent.ID = w_Country.Continent
    ;';

$stmtRow = $db->query($sqlQ); //execute sql query
while ($rowOne = $stmtRow->fetchObject()) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $sqlQ->Name;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $sqlQ->Name;?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
```

However, when testing said PHP code, I am receiving an error on the browser which replaces the row of data which should be present, and it reads:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in (directory name)

Comment: @Jigar Why did you edit the noise back in?

Answer (score 2):

It should be `$rowOne->Name` not `$sqlQ->Name`

`$sqlQ` is just a string and doesn't not contain the result from the query

Answer (score 0):

You are query is failing and returning false which causes the mentioned error

```
    $sqlQ = 'SELECT w_Continent.ID, w_Continent.NAME, w_Country.Name, w_Country.Continent FROM w_Continent JOIN w_Country ON w_Continent.ID = w_Country.Continent';
            $stmtRow = $db->query($sqlQ); //execute sql query
            while ($rowOne = $stmtRow->fetchObject()) {
                ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $rowOne->Name;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $rowOne->Name;?></td>
</tr>
<?php
```

Change the Query to above one and check. Notice semicolon(;) is removed.

Comment: Hi, I tested the SQL prior to using it in my code using PHPMyadmin and it returned the data I wanted without errors. Tried your suggestion however no luck. Thanks for the response!

Comment: that has to be $rowOne not $sqlQ. updated the check once